# Login with google BAD_AUTHENTICATION issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:652354120>, App: com.google.android.apps.maps, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mobilemaps.firstparty
                                           efl: Long live credential not available.
                                               at efm.b(:com.google.android.gms:3117)
                                               at efm.a(:com.google.android.gms:119)
                                               at edt.a(:com.google.android.gms:437)
                                               at eds.a(:com.google.android.gms:31404)
                                               at eds.a(:com.google.android.gms:297)
                                               at flg.a(:com.google.android.gms:1189)
                                               at flf.a(:com.google.android.gms:480)
                                               at flf.a(:com.google.android.gms:185)
                                               at eaa.a(:com.google.android.gms:370)
                                               at eaa.a(:com.google.android.gms:225)
                                               at bwf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:137)
                                               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
                                               at byl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:35)
                                               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

I have added SHA1 to signed apk and replaced google-services.json with new one. After release on app store getting this issue when going to login with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By enrolling Your application (“app”) in Google Play App Signing (GPAS) service,You consent to be bound by these terms,

> 1. Key Generation and Storage
>
>    1.1. GPAS is an optional service that provides a secure means of handling 
>      Your app signing key.
>
>    1.2. By enrolling Your existing app in GPAS, You agree to give Your 
>      existing app’s signing key to Google and to secure or delete Your copy(ies) 
>      of the key. For new apps, Google will generate a new app signing key for 
>      Your app.
>
>    1.3. You will have the ability to download and review any APKs you publish 
>      that are signed by Google.

You need to add SHA-1 fingerprint from App signing certificate to your fire base console also, this is the new update from google effective as of May 17th 2017.

[image: Please see image for reference]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a configuration issue with `Firebase`, `Google API` console and `google-services.json` file.

You would be aware of that release APK and debug APK have different SHA1 and different API keys for Google Services. So you need to add both of them on Firebase inside Project Setting. After doing this you need to download `google-services.json` file and put it in your project. Create a fresh release build with your keystore and publish you app on Google Play store.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, I did same as you mentioned but still issue persisting